# Create one or multiple gravitational points in sprite-kit scene

Tags: ios, physics, sprite-kit

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19328522/127493), I want to add some gravity in my sprite-kit scene. But the difference is my scene objects should be attracted to a point (at the middle of the scene). Or to multiple points.

I'm pretty sure I found something like that on the web, but I can't find it again.

I there a common way to acheive this, or should I calculate my own forces in the `update:` method?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this with gravity physics. You'll have to do this manually. Gravity in Sprite Kit works in a single direction, not towards a point. If you are wanting to create objects that orbit around several points then you'll have to work out the velocities manually based on distance from all the gravitational points.

Comment: Humm... thanks. But if I would develop this myself, I would use `applyForce:` method instead of working on velocities.

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot about that method. But yeah, you would have to do that rather than just set gravity points.

Comment: Oh actually, you'll have to do a fair amount of calculation though. If you have two or more points then you'll need to work out the force spread between all of them to apply to the object.

Comment: @Fogmeister, how about `[SKFieldNode radialGravityField]` ?

Comment: @danh yes that would work. At the time of my comment that didn't exist. radialGraivtyField was only added in iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you have to do is add gravity field nodes, and then turn OFF the gravity of the physicsWord so that your objects don't fall "down". You might have to set up some invisible borders to prevent the objects from orbiting the gravity field nodes, or possibly set a really friction.

You can also set the field strength of the gravity field nodes, which may save you from having to calculate the forces manually.

To turn off gravity (swift notation):

```
physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
```